# Possibility of omitting preposition phrase

Tags: grammaticality, phrases, comparisons, conjunction-reduction

I wonder if I can omit the parenthesized part here?

> Extraordinary success is achieved by working on commissions one after the other rather than (by doing all of them) simultaneously.

Comment: Could you please explain how it is possible to carry out a SERIES of steps or actions "simultaneously"?

Comment: "How" is not explained in the context. The writing passage is about achieving extraordinary success compared to a domino effect.

Answer (score 3):

It's common, probably preferred, to delete (omit) the second by-string or gerund-participial clause and just have the second adverbial (adverb, phrase ...) after 'rather than' in such sentences.

An example licensing this occurs in [AHD's definition of *arpeggio*](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/arpeggio):

> - Sense 1. *The sounding of the tones of a chord in rapid succession rather than simultaneously.*

Retrievable:

- *The sounding of the tones of a chord in rapid succession rather than the sounding of them/the tones of a chord simultaneously.*

Another example:

> - *So it's often worth taking a breath and then doing something quickly rather than hastily.*

[[University of Toronto; Faculty of Law](https://www.law.utoronto.ca/news/why-solomon-mckenzie-jd-2019-shares-pulse-profession-students)] [retrievable: [doing it]]

The related

- *We can cause disaster by doing something hastily rather than quickly.*

is of the same form as the sentence in question. [retrievable: [by doing it]]

As always with deletions, care must be taken to avoid ambiguous resulting sentences, or those with changed meanings ... and anything sounding ludicrous.

Comment: Thank you very much for your precise explanations and examples. It is very considerate of you to take references from various sources. It helped a lot.